# Laravel redireccionar a subdominio/subarpeta

Tags: laravel, wordpress, .htaccess

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Mi empresa comparte hosting con otras, y tenemos el subdominio dentro de una carpeta "public_html".
Al index de mi página puedo entrar perfectamente, es decir en [www.principal.com/mipagina](http://www.principal.com/mipagina) entra perfecto.

El problema es cuando redirecciono a páginas dentro de mi subdominio, se redireccionan al 404 Not Found de la pagina principal, es decir [www.principal.com/mipagina/nuevapagina](http://www.principal.com/mipagina/nuevapagina) 404 Not Found de principal.com

El archivo principal/public_html/.htaccess es

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

El archivo public_html/mipagina/.htaccess es

```
<FilesMatch ".(phtml|php|PhP|php5|suspected)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

El archivo public_html/mipagina/public/.htaccess es

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Debo aclarar que mi subdominio trabajaba perfectamente hasta hace unos dias, desde el mes de marzo que funcionaba muy bien.

Wordpress es la pagina principal del dominio, mi página en el subdominio está con el framework de Laravel.

Comment: de echo hace unos dias trabajaba de lo más bien, todo perfecto, solo que cambiaron algo en los archivos .htaccess, por eso creo que es algo a cambiar en estos archivos

Comment: Wordpress es la pagina principal del dominio, mi página en el subdominio está con el framework de Laravel.

Comment: Para aclarar... El redirect se hace de laravel a wordpress, al revés, de laravel a laravel, o cómo?

Comment: De laravel a laravel,

Comment: Algunas dudas... ¿Qué versión de laravel usas? ¿Sabes qué es lo que se cambió en el .htaccess, usas git o algún controlador de versiones para ver cómo estaba cuando funcionaba?

Comment: El hosting es basico, solo permitia hasta PHP Version 5.6.24 asi que debi usar Laravel 5.1, lamentablemente no se que pudieron cambiar en .htaccess y no tengo controlador de versiones perdon

Comment: las demas paginas funcionan correctamente

Comment: Hola Alejandro prueba agregando este código al .htaccess del subdominio.

`RewriteEngine On
# Redirect to public folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

Comment: lamentablemante no funciono, siguen redireccionando al principal